# Can't find entity model in Doctrine 2 / CodeIgniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I've been following some tutorials for getting Doctrine running, and seem to hang up when I try to insert an object into the database.  For reference, this is what I was following: [doctrine 2 tutorial](http://wildlyinaccurate.com/integrating-doctrine-2-with-codeigniter-2)

- Doctrine is installed in the application/libraries folder
- Doctrine.php bootstrapper is in the application/libraries folder
- A cli.php file is created in the application/ folder
- The tutorial did not say where to put my first Entity Model, so I put it in application/models

namespace Entity;

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{

/**
 * @Id
 * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=32, unique=true, nullable=false)
 */
protected $username;

/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
 */
protected $password;

/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=false)
 */
protected $email;

/**
 * The @JoinColumn is not necessary in this example. When you do not specify
 * a @JoinColumn annotation, Doctrine will intelligently determine the join
 * column based on the entity class name and primary key.
 *
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group")
 * @JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $group;

}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="group")
 */
class Group
{

/**
 * @Id
 * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=32, unique=true, nullable=false)
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="group")
 */
protected $users;

}
```

- Created my schema in the db without issue: php cli.php orm:schema-tool:create
- Got the the last step under the "Using Doctrine" setting
- Tried using the following code in my controller, and got an error

  ```
  $em = $this->doctrine->em;

  $user = new models\User;
  $user->setUsername('Joseph');
  $user->setPassword('secretPassw0rd');
  $user->setEmail('josephatwildlyinaccuratedotcom');

  $em->persist($user);
  $em->flush();
  ```

Produces

```
Fatal error: Class 'models\User' not found in C:\wamp\www\ci\application\controllers\Home.php on line 11
```

My only thoughts are that there might be something with the paths because I am in windows or that I put my entity model in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the tutorial you're following](http://wildlyinaccurate.com/integrating-doctrine-2-with-codeigniter-2), there is an important setting:

```
// With this configuration, your model files need to be in
// application/models/Entity
// e.g. Creating a new Entity\User loads the class from
// application/models/Entity/User.php
$models_namespace = 'Entity';
```

This is the namespace that your Doctrine entities (models) must use, which it appears you are doing correctly as you have `namespace Entity;` as the first line of your model. You can set it to whatever you want.

**With this configuration, your model files need to be in `application/models/Entity`**

When you create an instance of the entity, use the namespace you configured - not the model path:

```
// $user = new models\User; "models" is not the right namespace
$user = new Entity\User;
```

Comment: Hmm,  weird, not sure why he would list it as models\User in the tutorial.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that. It's probably a mistake - but I'm surprised there's nothing about it in the comments (I just left one).